# Javascript blocks in Visual Studio with riot.js

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, riot.js

Is there a way to have javascript block correctly displayed in Visual Studio when handling riot?

So we can use intelisence and all other neat features?

[image]

[image]

I've tried using `<script type="text/javascript`>` but that didn't help... what do you guys do?

Cause it's pretty bad every time we paste something in the `<script>` context, it re-formats everything to the left ... every single time :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be really simple...

Search in the Quick Launch (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) [top-right of Visual Studio] for *File Extensions* and add a new extension for:

```
tag --> HTML Editor
```

[image]

Comment: I did what you mention by it doesn't work for me. I am not seeing any difference at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, restarting Visual Studio also did nothing, but I closed the files and opened them again and it works now!

Comment: In VS11, searching  for _File Extensions_ didn't show the option. Instead look for _Text Editor File Extensio_ (yes, without _n_). It then shows up as the 4th entry.

Also, reopening the files was enough for highlighting to appear.